# How to sum up all neighbouring nonzero value in the middle of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am beginner in Python. I need to solve an issue with summing up neighboring nonzero value in a list.

Say, I have list called

```
a = [2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0].
```

In a, there will be multiple instances where the elements are nonzero. For example, 2 and 3 are neigbouring so I want to sum them up so I would get 5.

Then, there another neighbouring elements which are 3, 3 and 1. This is where I face problem because i want to sum it up to 7.

But in the code that I attempted on, it still print out 4, which is the sum of a[7] and a[8]. Is there any way I can avoid this?

```
c =[]
for i in range(1, len(a)): 
    if a[i-1] != 0:
        if a[i] != 0:
           tot = a[i] + a[i-1]
           c.append(tot)
           if a[i+1] != 0:
               tot = tot + a[i+1]
               c.append(tot)
    else:
        tot = 0;
        continue
```

Comment: what is the difference between summing elements and summing non-zero elements? adding 0 to a sum doesn't change it.

Comment: @Tacratis I think the OP is trying to find the different sums of all groups of non-zero values

Comment: Every nonzero value in a represent a block of instances. I need to sum up any nonzero value adjacent to each other to observe the length of the instances. Summing all elements would not help my objectives since I need it to be separate. 0 in the list means that there is a break in instances occurance. Hope you get what I mean

Comment: I understand now. It appears that others have already answered. Good luck :)

Comment: @Tacratis yup. thank you =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and a comprehension:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0]
>>> [sum(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(a, key=lambda x: x != 0) if k != 0]
[5, 1, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a simple generator function:

```
def groups(d):
  _sum = 0
  for i in d:
    if not i:
      if _sum:
        yield _sum
        _sum = 0
    else:
        _sum += i
  if _sum:
    yield _sum

print(list(groups([2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0])))
```

Output:

```
[5, 1, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to calculate sub-sums of consecutive non-zero elements.

How about:

```py
#!python3

from typing import List

def solve(arr: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    ret = []
    tmp = []
    for elem in arr+[0]:
        if elem != 0:
            tmp.append(elem)
        else:
            if len(tmp):
                ret.append(sum(tmp))
                tmp = []
    return ret

arr = [2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0]
assert(solve(arr) == [5, 1, 7])
```

Answer (score 0):

The original list 'a' is `[2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0]` where the neighboring non-zero elements in list 'a' are highlighted in bold text.

```
a = [2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0]
def fun(a):
    tot =[] # sub-list of list a
    val=0
    for i in a:
        if i==0:
            if val!=0:
                tot.append(val)
                val=0
        else:
            val+=i
    return tot

print(fun(a))
# output [5, 1, 7]
```